# How to write code for backspace and space in vb .net

Tags: vb.net

I am programming virtual keyboard with images, when I press the key it will display image but am not able to code space and backspace...

```
Dim myDir As String = "C:\Users\ASUBUSU\Desktop\keyboard\java pgm\"
Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(myDir & "sna.png")
Dim orgData = Clipboard.GetDataObject
Clipboard.SetImage(img)
Me.RichTextBox1.Paste()
Clipboard.SetDataObject(orgData)
```

How to write code for space and backspace.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in key press / key down / key up events.

```
    Private Sub form_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        Dim tmp As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs = e
        'Example for "Enter" key
        If tmp.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
            ' do something
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(8) Then
```

OR

```
If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back) Then
```

and so on.